# Metaprogramação com ruby on rails em uma partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramação

Pessoal estou trabalhando em um projeto Ruby on Rails e estou tralhando em um módulo (Financeiro) ele é vinculado a vários models,e dependendo da tela que o usuário está ele poderá fazer trazer uma tela com todas as movimentações financeiras daquele objeto. Porem queria fazer somente uma partial, na partial eu repassaria uma variavel (pega via metaprogramação) para um determinado campo (também pego via meta programação)

Para tentar gerar o link estou fazendo assim:

```
  <%%= link_to new_financial_path(<%= singular_table_name %>_id: @<%= singular_table_name %>.id), class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right', remote: true do %>
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <%= I18n.t('financials.new.new') %>
  <%% end %>
```

Porem o sistema está retornando

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `singular_table_name' for #<#<Class:0x007ff098434898>:0x007ff0b5c02eb8>
```

Did you mean?  singleton_method:
  app/views/financials/_financials.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_financials__financials_html_erb___3468020359035041149_70335661148700'

Alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer? Afinal ficaria muito mais fácil uma vez que a unica coisa que troca é o campo colum_id: @columvariable_id no caso o colum receberia o singular table name do controler em sí.

Comment: Se eu fizer assim

  <%%= link_to new_financial_path(<%= controller_name.singularize %>_id: @<%=  controller_name.singularize %>.id), class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right', remote: true do %>
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <%= I18n.t('financials.new.new') %>
  <%% end %>

O sistema imprime uma linha html assim:

<%= link_to new_financial_path(<%= controller_name.singularize %>_id: @reproduction.id), class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right', remote: true do %>  <%= I18n.t('financials.new.new') %> <% end %>

Comment: Você está recendendo esse erro por que não existe o método "singular_table_name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão é fazer assim:

1) Criar um concern para os modelos que podem ter extrato vão precisar utilizar. Lembrando que os concerns devem ficar na pasta models/concern assim o Rails automaticamente vai ler os concerns. O código ficaria algo assim:

```
module Financiable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do

    def transactions
      puts "Found: 30 itens"
    end
  end

end
```

2) Utilizar nos seus modelos o concern criado:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Financiable

end
```

2) Criar uma partial que recebe uma variável "model". Ficaria assim:

```
<%%= link_to new_financial_path(model.class.name, model.id), class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right', remote: true do %>
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <%= I18n.t('financials.new.new') %>
<%% end %>
```

3) Quando vc for usar a partial, usa assim:

```
<%= render partial: "financial_trancations", locals: { model: cliente } %>
```

Levando em consideração que vc tem uma variável chamada cliente do tipo model.

4) No controle que carrega os dados do partial deveria ter um método que ficaria assim:

```
def index
    clazz = params[:model_name].constantize.find(params[:model_id])
    @transactions = obj.transactions if class.respond_to?(:transactions)
end
```

Se tudo estiver no lugar correto isso deveria funcionar.

Abs!